# jQuery - Append dynamic content into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textarea

I have several elements that were dynamically added to my web page and now I'm trying to append them to textarea, but I keep getting only the last element to show up.

I figured I need to use **val()** instead of **append()**, but with **val()** I only get last option that was stated.

Can someone help me out? I'm trying to include all rows in the textarea.

I've recreated my problem in a snippet bellow.

```js
function getDetails() {
  // Clear content
  $("#save-content").val('');

  // First headline
  $("#save-content").val("First group: \n");

  // Content from first group
  $(".first-item .row").each(function(){
    var firstGroupName = $(this).find(".name").text();
    var firstGroupSurname = $(this).find(".surname").text();

    $("#save-content").val(firstGroupName + " " + firstGroupSurname  + "\n");
  });

  // Second headline
  $("#save-content").val("Second group: \n");

  // Content from second group
  $(".second-item .row").each(function(){
    var secondGroupName = $(this).find(".name").text();
    var secondGroupSurname = $(this).find(".surname").text();

    $("#save-content").val(secondGroupName + " " + secondGroupSurname  + "\n");
  });

  // Third headline
  $("#save-content").val("Third group: \n");

  // Content from third group
  $(".third-item .row").each(function(){
    var thirdGroupName = $(this).find(".name").text();
    var thirdGroupSurname = $(this).find(".surname").text();

    $("#save-content").val(thirdGroupName + " " + thirdGroupSurname  + "\n");
  });
}


$('button').on('click', function() {
  getDetails();
});
```

```css
.row>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imported-content">

  <div class="first-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">Penelope</div>
      <div class="surname">Smith</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">Jane</div>
      <div class="surname">Dalton</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">Kate</div>
      <div class="surname">Davidson</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="third-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">David</div>
      <div class="surname">Peters</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="name">Brad</div>
      <div class="surname">Lucas</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button>Import</button>

<textarea id="save-content" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the val when settings the val when you want to append.

For example:

```js
$('#save-content').val($('#save-content').val() + yourContentHere);
```

Comment: How would I go about importing all three? I would have to keep importing within the first val?

Comment: And how would that work with each statement?

Comment: No, you would change it where you want to append. e.g. this line:
`$("#save-content").val(secondGroupName + " " + secondGroupSurname  + "\n");`
would become `$("#save-content").val($("#save-content").val() + secondGroupName + " " + secondGroupSurname  + "\n");`

Comment: Yes, but I have three different groups so in this case I will end up with the whole third group. I've recreated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/uv8wf1sg/2/

Comment: You would change `$("#save-content").val(x)` to `$("#save-content").val($("#save-content").val() + x)` on every function you want appended instead of overwritten.